# Export clickstream data from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, clickstream, bigdata

I am trying to download clickstream data from Google Analytics but I am not able to get it in correct format i.e. time stamp, page-path etc. I have seen some post on BigQuery but I have never used SQL.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easy way. Google Analytics does not expose the client id via the API, so you cannot get user level data, and time based dimension allow breakdowns to the minute only, which is not granular enough.

You could store a more precise timestamp and the client id as custom dimensions (you might need to check your local laws and/or the privacy policy of your company to see if that kind of profile building requires permission by your users in your country).

Then you could pull url per client id, ordered by timestamp, via the [Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/). However that is not necessarily easy and on a large site you might run into the [API limits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas).

Comment: Thanks. I found this link but still not sure how to set this up http://daynebatten.com/2015/07/raw-data-google-analytics/#comment-2644